# samsung phone gets hot

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung

I have a Samsung s4 which easily gets hot even when doing light things and being on power saver mode, low brightness etc I've also tried factory reset

I'm on stock android 4.4

I've installed a temp app and initially the temperature is 26 Celsius and about 29 when browsing internet and about 35 when playing a game it gets hot on top of phone near earpiece

is this normal?

Comment: 26 C is practically room temperature, and 35 is less than the average person's body temperature. How much cooler do you really expect it to run? Electrical components naturally produce heat. The temperatures you're describing don't sound "hot" by computer standards at all.

Comment: OK.....I'm guessing the app isn't quite right cos the phone does actually get warm

but what sort of temp would you think is acceptable while playing..say candy crush

Comment: it's not normal at all, but i think you need to get used to it because it is the hottest phone i have come across personally. Temperature described by you is wrong because that sound pretty cool. Try using clean master  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

May be this can work for you. Reformat your micro SD card. Some users have reported that media server can cause the phone to overheat. Save a copy of your files in your microSD card to your computer then reformat if.

Go to Menu Select Settings 
 Tap More Select Storage Touch Format SD
 card Review the message and touch Format SD card Tap Delete all
 Remove then reinsert the microSD card afterwards.

If the problem continues, this means that you have a phone defect causing it.For more details you can refer Samsung India site.

Answer (score -1):

If it get really warm (greater than 35C) try Clean Master (like reachrk suggested) and Battery Doctor.

Clean Master will clear the RAM, which when loaded will cause the CPU to overheat dramatically trying to process all the data. Battery Doctor will close all background apps, limiting power consumption and thus reducing heat generation.